# Verifying my knowledge of how an empty Scanner reacts in Java

Tags: java

Is this true?

**If you have a scanner attached to System.in, and it's current Buffer is 100% empty, it will always pause whenever it encounters a call to the scanner object.**

```
scan.hasNext();

scan.nextInt();

scan.nextBoolean();
```

I just want to make sure I am understanding what is going on properly. I am seeing that it pauses when it encounters these in my little test programs but I am wonder if the program *always* pauses when it encounters these or if it only pauses at these calls when the buffer is empty. Thank you.

Comment: My understanding (which I'm not 100% sure of): It blocks if it needs more input.  So for `nextInt()`, it looks at the input that it's read but hasn't yet consumed, and if it can't find a token, then it reads more input, which may involve waiting for the user to type some in.  (But keep in mind `System.in` could be redirected to get input from a file, in which case there wouldn't be any pause.)  This also means if the buffer (unused input) is not "empty" but contains only spaces, it will still pause because it won't find a token in the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Scanner` needs more characters, then it will attempt to read them from the source.  If the source is at its EOF position<sup>1</sup> then the `Scanner` method will return `false` or throw an exception (depending on which one you are talking about).  Otherwise, it will block.

But the situation is complicated by the fact that those `Scanner` methods will not *necessarily* attempt to get characters from the underlying source.  In particular, the `Scanner` itself acts as a buffer for characters that have been read by previous `Scanner` calls.  So for example:

```
  scanner.hasNext();  // This may attempt to read characters
  scanner.hasNext();  // This won't attempt to read characters
```

On top of that, the source you are reading from could itself be buffered, either within the JVM or externally.

---

So, you asked:

> If you have a scanner attached to `System.in`, and it's current Buffer is 100% empty, it will always pause whenever it encounters a call to the scanner object.

What happens depends on:

- what you mean by "its current Buffer",
- the nature of the Java<sup>2</sup> and OS-level<sup>3</sup> streams attached to `System.in`, and
- the state of the stream.

But, the answer is No.  It won't always pause.

---

<sup>1 - Determining this may entail a `read` syscall ... which will return immediately if the native stream is at the EOF position.</sup>

<sup>2 - For instance, you could use `System.setIn(...)` to *change* what `System.in` refers to.</sup>

<sup>3 - For instance, standard input could be coming from a file or another process.</sup>